# Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to execute following code:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <loginResponse>
            <result>
                <metadataServerUrl>
                    https://na3.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/28.0/00D50000000IdrE
                </metadataServerUrl>
                <passwordExpired>false</passwordExpired>
                <sandbox>false</sandbox>
                <serverUrl>
                    https://abc.com/services/Soap/c/28.0/00D50000000IdrE
                </serverUrl>
                <sessionId>
                    00D50000000IdrE!AREAQK4VYXRaHoL_uRvOi.QXXw3ahAt2Cge254wygiW7cr_f6DVa2pDC6g57w5IE
                    fidAu3ZRsJFBN5Bwb6DVhF18zKFiVVyT
                </sessionId>
                <userId>00550000001Dd4uAAC</userId>
                <userInfo>
                    <accessibilityMode>false</accessibilityMode>
                    <currencySymbol>$</currencySymbol>
                    <orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>5242880
                    </orgAttachmentFileSizeLimit>
                    <orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>USD</orgDefaultCurrencyIsoCode>
                    <orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>false
                    </orgDisallowHtmlAttachments>
                    <orgHasPersonAccounts>false</orgHasPersonAccounts>
                    <organizationId>00D50000000IdrEEAS</organizationId>
                    <organizationMultiCurrency>false</organizationMultiCurrency>
                    <organizationName>3CLogic</organizationName>
                    <profileId>00e500000017al5AAA</profileId>
                    <roleId xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sessionSecondsValid>7200</sessionSecondsValid>
                    <userDefaultCurrencyIsoCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <userEmail>ramana@3clogic.com</userEmail>
                    <userFullName>Ramana</userFullName>
                    <userId>00550Dd4uAAC</userId>
                    <userLanguage>en_US</userLanguage>
                    <userLocale>en_US</userLocale>
                    <userName>raman@gmail.com.com</userName>
                    <userTimeZone>America/New_York</userTimeZone>
                    <userType>Standard</userType>
                    <userUiSkin>Theme3</userUiSkin>
                </userInfo>
            </result>
        </loginResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
EOD;
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('env', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ ');
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('def', 'urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com');
$result = $sxe->xpath('/env:Envelope/env:Body/def:loginResponse/def:result/def:serverUrl');
?>
```

However, getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace()
```

I am using php version 5.0.5. However, whith php version 5.1.0 and 5.5.3 I am getting this error but also no output. I am trying to extract value of xml tag 'serverUrl'. 
Please help. If possible please suggest solution for php 5.0.5

Comment: Don't even touch it unless you are using PHP version 5.2.0 or greater. [SimpleXMLElement::registerXPathNamespace Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) First line under the heading: `(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)`

Comment: Thanks...can you suggest me some solution to extract xml tag value in this case

Comment: PHP 5.0 has been [unsupported for almost exactly 8 years](http://www.php.net/eol.php). The best solution to *any* problem with such an old version is to update to a supported version. I realise that isn't always possible, but you will certainly need to be *very aware* of the limitations of using such an old version, and only use features you are sure existed in that version.

Comment: Oh, and regards "getting no output" - nowhere in your code appears to be attempting any output; the last thing you show is assigning to the variable `$result`.

Comment: try with DOM it had xml namespace support before simplexml however no guarantee it fits your needs. You will need to do the legwork your own because 5.0.x is dead, so no broad interest to actually have and answer this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a long-time dead PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath functionality was only added to SimpleXML in PHP 5.2.0 (which is itself [more than 2 and a half years beyond "End of Life"](http://www.php.net/eol.php)), so if you're genuinely stuck on as ancient a version of PHP as 5.0.5, you'll have to come up with a different solution.

Luckily, your XPath expression is extremely basic, other than its use of namespaces, and the [`->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) has been able to handle those since PHP 5.0.1.

This code should therefore run fine under any version of PHP since then:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

// Define some short identifiers for namespaces without relying on their prefix in the XML
define('NS_ENV', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
define('NS_SFORCE', 'urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com');

// $sxe already represents the soapenv:Envelope node, so we don't need to mention that
$result = $sxe
    ->children(NS_ENV)->Body
    ->children(NS_SFORCE)->loginResponse->result->serverUrl;

// $result is now the SimpleXML object for the `serverUrl` node(s)
// (unlike with ->xpath(), which returns a plain PHP array of "search results")
echo trim($result);
```

Here's [a live sample](http://3v4l.org/lhBma) showing it evaluated in various different versions of PHP.